# Управление системным временем C++

Tags: c++, windows, сервер, запрос, время

**Подскажите, как используя С++ поменять системное время и что можно сделать, что бы узнать локальное время?**

Решил немного подкорректировать свой вопрос. Суть в том, что я не знаю, как это реализовать. Буду рад, если подскажите, где можно было бы по подробнее узнать об этой теме.

Я пытаюсь написать программу на C++, которая будет менять часовой пояс на локальной машине в зависимости от IP. IP переодически, в основном при перезагрузке, меняется.

Примерно выстроил этапы работы программы:

1. Определяется IP;
2. IP соотносится с часовым поясом;
3. Текущий часовой пояс меняется на тот, что связан с IP;

После этого программа мониторит изменения IP адреса, если он меняется, процедура повторяется.

*Еще раз уточню - Я пишу программу, для того, что бы она выставляла время на моем компьютере, в зависимости от того, какой у меня в данный момент IP.*

ОС - windows (win 10)

Comment: man settimeofday

Comment: для начала лучше определиться с осью. А потом разобраться и отключить  (или настроить?) ntp

Comment: не нужно самому выставлять системное время. Будет бардак. Выставляйте правильно часовой пояс.

Comment: Мне нужно что бы в зависимости от моего IP менялось мое системное время.

Comment: @AlexWanderman: Тогда передайте вашему архитектору, что он идиот.

Comment: "узнать часовой пояс для даного ip" и как это можно реализовать в С++?

Comment: А тут все очень сложно и неоднозначно. Более того, "правильный часовой пояс для нужной точки на карте" очень легко может поменятся. 
Но это пол беды. Очень часто, по айпи вообще ничего нельзя однозначно "вычислить". Я много раз встречал ситуацию, когда по айпи одна страна, а по факту - совершенно другая (и это без впн и подобного). Поэтому, должна быть просто банально таблица соответствий апйи - часовой пояс.

Comment: Мне удобнее всего на этом языке прогрмму писать.

Comment: Надо обозначить  в вопросе что "я пользуюсь супер-анонимайзером" или особым VPN, поэтому время прыгает, и зависит от часового пояса IP выданного анонимайзером или VPN. Тогда будет понятно почему так со временем.

Answer (score 2):

Это `SetSystemTime` в Windows API.

Подробнее - [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Должен также написать, что занятие сие считаю крайне нездоровым...

Comment: Спасибо, но почему же "нездоровым"?

Comment: Ну как вам сказать... Если вы хотите обмануть кого-то, то делать это ценой того, чтобы ваш обман стал правдой - как-то тяжеловесно :) Кроме того, прыжки во времени неизвестно как отразятся на самой системе, которая будет не понимать, что и когда ей следует делать... В ней же не только ваша программа работать будет.

Comment: @nick_n_a "Подскажите, как используя С++ поменять системное время". Я ответил на эту часть вопроса.

Comment: "Если вы хотите обмануть кого-то" Я для себя прогрмму пишу, просто не очень удобно в ручную время менять. Я не собираюсь никого обманывать.

Comment: @AlexWanderman Вообще-то, здесь никто никому ничего не запрещает :) Так что дерзайте!

Answer (score 0):

Мой ответ не даёт 100% ответ, но я всётаки обьясню куда копать. Если у кого есть готовое решение - то это хорошо.

Прежде всего вам нужно определить часовую поправку типа `tim_plus = gettimezone(ip)`
Где  tim_plus  будет разница между временем на сервере и временем на компьютере пользователя. (что б не было конфликта с СУБД и т.п)

А затем выводить на экран выводить информацию так `print(timetostr(time + tim_plus))` где  tim_plus - разница во премени.

Теперь о том как получить пояс, укажу три способа.

1. javascript клиента. Вам никто не мешает сделать скрипт который сообщит вам системное время с поясом на компе клиента типа

   ```
   <script>
   if (!document.getElementByIf("haszone")) { // Например кешировать (не обязательно)
             var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var loc = location.href;
   var dop = loc.split("/");
   loc  = loc.replace(dop[dop.length - 1],"zone_handler.aspx");            
   xmlhttp.open('POST', loc, false);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");            
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
   var d = new Date();
   xmlhttp.send("d=" + d);
     }
   ```

Таким образом вы можете обработать запрос и хранить ip и поправку. Используя тот же js можна обновить страницу клиенту например спустя 5 сек, что б уже после обработки времени сделалась корректировка, но тогда нужно поставить в `<input type=hidden id=haszone>`  отметку что запрос обработан, иначе зациклится.  Обработчик повесить на страницу `zone_handler.aspx`. Обработчик напишите самостоятельно, в параметре d в него будет передано время на компьютере.

Способ 2, скачать в интернете базу ip может тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/193024/ или в другом месте, и там же есть sql-скрипты как использовать базу.

Способ 3. Подключить платный сервис определения геолокации например тут http://htmlweb.ru/php/example/get_ip2.php

Ну и как дополнительный способ, самому составить базу геолокации используя ip ваших клиентов, если таких не много. Так же можно улучшить базу если например клиенты только РФ можно найти таблицу для РФ.

И последнее, ещё можно посмотрель параметр в http-заголовке **Accept-Languages**, исходя из языков можно весьма приблизительно определить пояс, но если есть там украинский или польский или немецкий язык и страна использует один пояс - то по-языку иногда можно определить пояс.

Comment: Спасибо, но это не совсем то, что нужно. Хотя база данных пригодится. Я пишу программу, для того, что бы она выставляла время на моем компьютере, в зависимости от того, какой у меня IP.

Comment: Т.е. вы перерехали в другую страну - у вас поменялось IP и время?

Comment: Тогда похоже вам подходит только два других способа 2 и 3.

Comment: Я никуда не переезжал, я использую vpn. А при перезагрузке он соответственно переподключается и меняет IP, соответственно сайты видят несоответствие во врменени. Для того, что бы не нужно было в ручную время менять я и пишу эту программу.

Comment: Тогда для вас лучший способ другой - напишите программу которая скачает сайт, например это http://ru.infobyip.com/ , проанализирует, и выдаст вам часовой пояс, например по "местное время". При перегрузке трафика сайт может менятся.